# Quais tipos de coleções e suas diferenças em java?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Há muitas tipos de coleções em java e tenho a dificuldade de saber as seguintes questões apresentadas abaixo:

- Quais as diferenças entre elas?
- Quais situações e/ou casos devo utilizar cada uma das diferentes coleções?

Comment: Sua pergunta pode ser respondida na documentação oficial, sendo a diferenças: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html ; e uso: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html

Comment: Complementando: [How to choose which Java collection class to use?](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Quais as diferenças entre elas?

Primeiramente é importante entender que *Collection* é um termo que pode ser ambíguo, pois existem:

- *collection* (ou coleções em tradução livre): Que seriam qualquer estrutura de dados em que objetos são armazenados e podem ser iterados;
- *Collection* (`java.util.Collection`): Que é uma interface que possui as subinterfaces `Set`, `List` e `Queue`; e
- *Collections* (`java.util.Collections`): Que é uma classe com alguns métodos estáticos para serem usados com subclasses de `Collection`.

Enquanto `Set`, `List` e `Queue` além de serem coleções (ou *collection*, com "c" minúsculo) também são `Collection`'s, pois implementam a interface `java.util.Collection`. O mesmo não acontece com o `Map`, que apesar de poder ser considerado uma coleção, ele não implementa a interface `java.util.Collection`.

Veja abaixo:

[image: Diagrama UML com relações de herança de classes]

As principais diferenças dentre as interfaces citadas acima são:

- `List`: Lista de coisas;
- `Set`: Lista de coisas sem repetição;
- `Map`: Lista com chave-valor, sendo que a chave deve ser única; e
- `Queue`: Fila.

Cada interface possui classes que as implementam. Como são muitas vou apenas colocar o quadro comparativo de cada uma delas, que acho que resume muito bem a funcionalidade de cada uma:

[image: tabela com as classes]

Significado de:

- *Ordered* (ordenada): Quando uma coleção é ordenada, quer dizer que é possível iterar os elementos da coleção em uma ordem específica e não aleatória.
- *Sorted* (classificada): Quando uma coleção é classificada, quer dizer que a ordem dos elementos da coleção é determinada de acordo com alguma regra, conhecida como ordem de classificação.

Fonte: [SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071591060)

> Quais situações ou casos devo utilizar cada uma das diferentes coleções?

A situação depende da sua necessidade, olhando as diferenças listadas acima fica muito claro quando deve-se escolher uma ou outra coleção.