# Em que ordem uma Set é armazenada? Aleatória?

Tags: java, classificação, set, hashset

Quando eu armazeno algo dentro de um `Set`, a ordem em que ele armazena é aleatória?

E como eu poderia ordenar um conjunto `Set`?

Comment: Aqui tem uma visão mais geral dos diferentes tipos de coleções do Java: [Quais tipos de coleções e suas diferenças em java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34605/3117)

Comment: Relacionado (para C#): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29226/criar-lista-sem-valores-duplicados

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307385/64969

Answer (score 7):

O `Set` é apenas uma interface. A ordem depende da implementação.

O `HashSet` não tem garantia nenhuma de ordem. Na prática é aleatório.

O `LinkedHashSet` mantém a ordem na qual os elementos são inseridos.

O `TreeSet` ordena os elementos de acordo com a ordenação natural (crescente, alfabética, etc). É possível passar um `Comparator` no construtor para especificar como ele deve ordenar caso a ordenação natural não exista ou não seja a desejada.

---

Para instanciar o `TreeSet` com um `Comparator`, podemos usar uma classe a parte, uma classe anônima ou uma referência a um método (java 8):

Com classe a parte:

```
public void instanciaElemento() {
    TreeSet<SuaClasse> = new TreeSet<>(new MeuComparator());
}

public static class MeuComparator implements Comparator<SuaClasse> {
    @Override
    public int compare(SuaClasse a, SuaClasse b) {
        // Implementação...
        // Retorna 1 se a é depois de b, -1 se a é antes de b ou 0 se os dois são iguais.
    }
}
```

Com classe anônima:

```
public void instanciaElemento() {
    TreeSet<SuaClasse> = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<> {
        @Override
        public int compare(SuaClasse a, SuaClasse b) {
            // Implementação...
            // Retorna 1 se a é depois de b, -1 se a é antes de b ou 0 se os dois são iguais.
        }
    });
}
```

Com referência a método:

```
public void instanciaElemento() {
    TreeSet<SuaClasse> = new TreeSet<>(EstaClasse::metodoComparador);
}

private static int metodoComparador(SuaClasse a, SuaClasse b) {
    // Implementação...
    // Retorna 1 se a é depois de b, -1 se a é antes de b ou 0 se os dois são iguais.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Embora `TreeSet` faça a ordenação dos elementos, a decisão de usar esta implementação não deve ser feita apenas para o caso de se precisar ordenar a lista em um momento.

Ao instanciar um `TreeSet`, `HashSet` ou `LinkedHashSet` você deve considerar as vantagens de cada uma, principalmente no que se refere ao custo para adicionar e ao custo para recuperar um elemento. Algumas implementações funcionam melhor para adicionar vários elementos, outras para recuperar elementos e tudo isso depende da variedade dos objetos colocados lá dentro.

Se você simplesmente tem um conjunto e quer gerar uma lista ordenada, basta usar o construtor do `ArrayList` que recebe um `Collection` qualquer.

Assim:

```
Set<String> conjunto = new HashSet<>();
conjunto.add("Jose");
conjunto.add("Maria");
conjunto.add("Joao");
conjunto.add("Maria");
System.out.println(conjunto);

//conjunto -> lista
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>(conjunto);
Collections.sort(lista);
System.out.println(lista);
```

### [Exemplo no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/XHfwdX)

Answer (score 4):

Para completar a resposta do @Victor

O `set`  por si só não guarda nada, visto que é uma `Interface`:

Artigo sobre `set` [aqui](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3669/trabalhando-com-a-interface-set-no-java.aspx)

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Em que ordem uma Set é armazenada? Aleatória?

Sim

*Exemplo:*

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class HashSetExample {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // HashSet declaration
      HashSet<String> hset = 
               new HashSet<String>();

      // Adding elements to the HashSet
      hset.add("Apple");
      hset.add("Mango");
      hset.add("Grapes");
      hset.add("Orange");
      hset.add("Fig");
      //Addition of duplicate elements
      hset.add("Apple");
      hset.add("Mango");
      //Addition of null values
      hset.add(null);
      hset.add(null);

      //Displaying HashSet elements
      System.out.println(hset);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
[null, Mango, Grapes, Apple, Orange, Fig]
```

[link para este exemplo](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashset-class-in-java-with-example/)

Se por caso tencionas fazer um `Set` de algum objecto criado por ti, deves de implementar `Comparable`:

Por exemplo este para uma classe conta:

```
public class Conta implements Comparable<Conta> {

    private int numero;
    private String titular;
    // outros metodos e atributos

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Conta outraConta) {
        if (this.numero < outraConta.numero) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.numero > outraConta.numero) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Tens um bom artigo [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/ordenando-colecoes-com-comparable-e-comparator/)

Comment: Implementei o Comparable em uma classe e pus vários objetos dessa classe em um HashSet, mas ao mandar imprimir a lista ela não estava ordenada. O que fiz de errado? :/

Comment: @Math Está no sitio indicado para publicar a sua duvida juntamente com o código devidamente indentado ;) supondo que deve ser uma espécie de brincadeira/teste e entrando na mesma :)... Existe vários motivos talvez o teu comparable está mal implementado, ou a resposta que eu penso que tu queres é esqueceu de implementar o equals e hashCode? (estou certo ou nada a ver?)

Comment: A verdade é que o HashSet é aleatório, independente se você implementar ou não o Comparable isso não faz a menor diferença para essa classe. Quem usa o Comparable (e o Comparator) é na verdade o TreeSet. Veja: `It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.` no link: [HashSet - Java SE7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Mudando o código de HashSet para TreeSet ele passa a exibir os objetos de forma ordenada definida pelo método `compareTo()`. Tendeu? ;-)

Comment: pufff sim, fico lhe muito agradecido por esta explicação, como reparou estava mesmo convencido que era possível ;) e eu a pensar que te tinha "apanhado" na resposta anterior, foi mais como bater de frente numa parede com a verdadeira resolução :O mais uma vez muito obrigado @Math