# Quais as diferenças entre TreeSet, HashSet e LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, coleção

A ideia do Set é não permitir elementos repetidos, no java existem três implementações `TreeSet`, `HashSet` e `LinkedHashSet` encontrei algumas diferenças [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40199/91), gostaria de saber detalhamente se existem outras e em qual caso/cenário cada coleção se destaca.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O que muda são as estruturas internas. Algumas dão mais garantias que outras.

Não vou entrar em detalhes do que é um `Set`, não parece ser o propósito da questão.

### `TreeSet`

Só se aplica a elementos com ordenação absoluta. Se eles não forem comparáveis (`Comparable`), você pode ensinar com um comparador (`Comparator`).

Por baixo dos panos, usa uma árvore de busca balanceada (acho que árvore binária, a rubro-negra, mas não lembro da fonte dessa informação nem se os detalhes internos já mudaram).

Como é uma árvore balanceada, todas as operações são feitas em `O(lg(n))`. Tem garantias de que você vai iterar diferente da ordem em que os elementos foram inseridos.

### `HashSet`

Por baixo, usa uma tabela de espalhamento que aponta para uma lista ligada de nós. Quando há colisão, insere-se no início da lista ligada.

Só aplicável para objetos que tenham função de `hash`. Em Java, todos os objetos tem essa função ([`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--)), então todos são candidatos para essa coleção =D

> Se você desejar usar um número de espalhamento próprio, como se fosse fornecido um `IntFunction<T>` para gerar o número, então você precisa criar sua própria coleção ou fazer um `HashSet<MyHashWrapper<T>>`, onde `MyHashWrapper<T>` seria um envólucro que contenha um objeto `T` e uma função de `hash` própria.

No mundo ideal, operações em `O(1)`, mas pode degradar para `O(n)`.

Não há garantia de ordem de iteração.

### `LinkedHashSet`

Idem ao `HashSet`, porém os nós da lista ligada da colisão tem uma ligação extra. Essa ligação garante que seja possível iterar na ordem de inserção. Daí, você tem a garantia que itera na mesma ordem da inserção.

## Quando usar cada um?

De maneira geral, o `HashSet` você usaria por preguiça. Performance razoavelmente boa na maioria dos casos. Dificilmente necessita-se acessar na mesma ordem da inserção.

O `LinkedHashSet` custo dois centavos de memória extra e um de processamento, deve ser usado para extrair em ordem de inserção.

Já o `TreeMap` teria duas possíveis utilizações:

- evitar a degradação do `hash`
- iterar sempre na ordem crescente

Caso a sua aplicação precise percorrer muitas e muitas vezes esses valores na ordem crescente, então pode fazer sentido usar o `TreeMap` para este fim. Caso não precise fazer essa iteração constantemente, mas apenas de vez em quando, transformar do `Set` para uma `List` e ordenar não será um grande *overhead*. Daí a preguiça fala mais alto e eu usaria `HashSet` =)